# OpenVPN Connection successful but no IPs reachable

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have set up an OpenVPN-Server and can connect successfully, but after the connection is established I am not able to reach any internal destinations (192.168.10.0/24).

The problem seems to only occur on Linux(Ubuntu 18.04.1)/Android systems as I am able to reach the internal destinations from a MacOS (Viscosity) and from a Windows System (Official OpenVPN client) with just importing the ovpn.
The problem also occurs on my Android phone using the "OpenVPN Connect"-App.

On Ubuntu, I installed "apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome" and imported the ovpn. The connection is established successfully, but no network address is pingable/reachable.

Destination network: 192.168.10.0/24

OpenVPN Tunnel Address space: 10.0.8.0/24

Here is the routing table:

```
user@Ubnt:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.8.1        0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp4s0
10.0.8.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     50     0        0 tun0
84.112.13.233   192.168.43.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlp4s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp4s0
192.168.10.0    10.0.8.1        255.255.255.0   UG    50     0        0 tun0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp4s0
192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    600    0        0 wlp4s0
```

And here is the ovpn:

```
dev tun
persist-tun
persist-key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
tls-client
client
resolv-retry infinite
remote extern.dummy.com 1194 udp
lport 0
verify-x509-name "extern.dummy.com" name
auth-user-pass
remote-cert-tls server
compress 

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>

key-direction 1

<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
...
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

I hope someone can point me in the right direction as I was not able to find any solution after searching various forums.

Thanks in advance

Comment: OK, it seems that the problem lies within the gnome-extension. As I am able to successfully connect and reach the target subnet without issues when connecting using the OpenVPN client directly from terminal: "sudo openvpn /home/User1/Desktop/pfSense.ovpn"